# filter_var function vs Reg. Expressions

Tags: php

I think this is probably a fairly easily answered question:

Im new to regular expressions in general, but I have recently heard that filter_var is almost replaceing the expressions.

I can see, after looking at the function, that I could validate emails in general.  But is there capabilities to narrow the validation?

My issue is im trying to validate an email to only return true if it ends in @boisestate.edu OR @u.boisestate.edu.  I cant seem to figure out if filter_var has those kinds of specific capabilities.  Any help would really be appreciated!  Also, if you have a reg expression or filter_var function that would suit this validation...Id really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `filter_var` to validate the e-mail, *then* check if it ends in `@boisestate.edu`, etc. afterward using `substr_compare($theEmail, $theSuffix, -strlen($theSuffix), strlen($theSuffix)) === 0`.